# Lista dinamica ordenada com dados de busca

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-service

Estou com um problema para exibir dados vindos de um banco de dados de forma ordenada, tenho um campo para o usuário entrar com o ID e ele retorna o nome do usuário, e quando for buscando mais usuários os anteriores devem se manter.

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET['a'];
    if($a == "buscar"){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE = $id ");
        $row = ibase_fetch_row($sql);
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

Desta forma cada nova busca ele elimina o resultado anterior

Comment: Já cogitou a possibilidade de fazer requisições assíncronas com AJAX?

Comment: Entao amigo, nao conheço muito bem ajax, estou iniciando os trabalhos com php. Segui a dica de um colega aqui do forum para fazer com jquery ou javascript, porém nao estou conseguindo pensar em uma solução

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer ir buscando e manter as bucas anteriores, você consegue fazer isso usando `javascript`.

Vamos levar em consideração que estou usando o `jquery`

```
// Estrutura HTML

    <ul id="lista"></div>


// Estrutura JS
$.ajax({
   url: 'SUA URL',
   data: {
      id: // ID PASSADO
   },
   success: function(data){
      $('#lista').append('<li>'+data.nome+'</li>')
   }
})
```

feito isso, sempre que seu `ajax` for executado ele vai adicionar o novo resultando, mantendo o anterior.

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET['a'];
    $retorno = array();
    if($a == "buscar"){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE = $id ");
        $row = ibase_fetch_row($sql);
        $retorno['nome'] = $row[0];
    }

   die(json_encode($retorno));
?>
```

Esse é um exemplo superficial, basta adaptar

Comment: isso mesmo, ir buscando e manter as buscas anteriores

Comment: porém nunca vi nada de ajax, conseguiria me auxilir no chat ?

Comment: Sim, abre um chat que te ajudo

Comment: beleza, nao estou conseguindo abrir haha

Comment: Como estender essa discussão para o bate papo ?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67252/lista-ajax